# Last logging parameter of Azure Function (ILogger or TraceWriter) not accepted

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-webjobs

After upgrading my own project from an earlier (a few months back) version of Azure Functions to current, I get the following error upon launching from VS.

> GetLoginUrl: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method 'Login.GetLoginUrl'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Cannot bind parameter 'log' to type ILogger. Make sure the parameter Type is supported by the binding. If you're using binding extensions (e.g. ServiceBus, Timers, etc.) make sure you've called the registration method for the extension(s) in your startup code (e.g. config.UseServiceBus(), config.UseTimers(), etc.).

Before, I used to have `TraceWriter log` as the last parameter to my methods but then I found out I should be using `ILogger` instead. Before I made the change, I was getting the same error as above.

The `ILogger` seems to be mapped to assembly `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions`. Perhaps this is why it is not recognized? Which `ILogger` should be used? Here is the method signature.

```
[FunctionName("GetLoginUrl")]
public static HttpResponseMessage GetLoginUrl(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = null)]HttpRequestMessage req,
    ILogger log)
```

I did not try to deploy this to Azure.

Unfortunately, creating a brand new Functions project does not help as there are no .CS files to look up to in order to correct this.

Comment: Your code looks exactly like my working code that uses ILogger with Azure Functions. Does the problem go away if you delete all referenced NuGet packages except for `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions` then add the specific ones you need back?

Comment: Yes, exactly! That does it. Please see my other comment for details. Briefly, all "Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.*" assemblies were redundant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions` is the correct assembly.

You are probably referencing some older NuGet packages directly (e.g. `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs`). If so, be sure to remove it. Unless you are using some additional binding, your `csproj` references should look as simple as this:

```
<ItemGroup>           
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="1.0.4" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: You hit the nail on the head! Thanks. I suppose the old project template added `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs` and a few others. Removing all of those and leaving `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions` 1.0.4 makes things work perfectly.

Comment: I spent two days trying to figure this out; I still don't know why exactly but some other package references were conflicting, and thankfully I was able to remove them. So -- the lesson is to watch out for references to `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions` in places that you don't expect. :)