# ILogger instance not initialized in parameter of precompiled Azure function

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

I have written a precompiled Azure Function project in Visual Studio 2017 in C# following the steps described [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2017/03/16/publishing-a-net-class-library-as-a-function-app/) or [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/wiki/Precompiled-functions). I want to replace `TraceWriter` logging with Application Insights logging through the Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger interface. For that I updated the Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs Nuget package to version [2.1.0-beta1](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/releases/tag/v2.1.0-beta1), which includes the [ILogger](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/wiki/ILogger) binding that enables binding directly to the Application Insights logger. I have also added the app setting `APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY` with a valid Application Insights instrumentation key. After replacing the `TraceWriter` parameter of my function with an `ILogger` parameter, I trigger the function and get the following error response:

```
{
    "id": "497256d0-1c3a-4a10-a1cc-41b771305338",
    "requestId": "e546219e-7e38-4fa7-80cf-b06e0b8f4018",
    "statusCode": 500,
    "errorCode": 0,
    "messsage": "Exception while executing function: Functions.HelloHttpTrigger -> Exception binding parameter 'log' -> No value was provided for parameter 'log'.",
    "errorDetails": "Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.FunctionInvocationException : Exception while executing function: Functions.HelloHttpTrigger ---> System.InvalidOperationException : Exception binding parameter 'log' ---> System.InvalidOperationException : No value was provided for parameter 'log'.\r\n   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Bindings.Invoke.ClassInvokeBinding`1.BindAsync(BindingContext context)\r\n   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Triggers.TriggeredFunctionBinding`1.BindCoreAsync[TTriggerValue](ValueBindingContext context,Object value,IDictionary`2 parameters) \r\n   End of inner exception\r\n   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.DelayedException.Throw()\r\n   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.ExecuteWithWatchersAsync(IFunctionInstance instance,IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameters,TraceWriter traceWriter,CancellationTokenSource functionCancellationTokenSource)\r\n   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.ExecuteWithLoggingAsync(??)\r\n   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.ExecuteWithLoggingAsync(??) \r\n   End of inner exception\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.ExecuteWithLoggingAsync(??)\r\n   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.TryExecuteAsync(IFunctionInstance functionInstance,CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.ExceptionDispatchInfoDelayedException.Throw()\r\n   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.JobHost.CallAsyncCore(MethodInfo method,IDictionary`2 arguments,CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.ScriptHost.CallAsync(String method,Dictionary`2 arguments,CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.WebScriptHostManager.HandleRequestAsync(FunctionDescriptor function,HttpRequestMessage request,CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.Controllers.FunctionsController.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext,CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at async System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request,CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at async System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request,CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.Handlers.SystemTraceHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request,CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.Handlers.WebScriptHostHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request,CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at async System.Web.Http.HttpServer.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request,CancellationToken cancellationToken)"
}
```

So no instance of `ILogger` can be created. However, if I create a project with a function script, instead of a precompiled function, then the ILogger instance is correctly instantiated. Does this mean that the instantiation of ILogger only works with function scripts?? I hope that's not the case, so what should I add to the setup of my precompled function to make it work?

Comment: Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/a/46471220/1171619 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As indicated in the answer pointed by Mikhail I had to download the Nuget package `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions` v1.0.4. But to be able to install it I had to install version 2.1.0-beta4 of packages `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs` and `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions`; and version 1.0.0-beta4 of  `Microsoft.Azure.Webjobs.Extensions.Http`. And to get the project to build I had to add `<Target Name="RunResolvePublishAssemblies" />` in the project file.

Answer (score 1):

I just had this issue trying to get a .net Core 2.1 function app using `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions@1.0.14` running on Azure.

I needed to set `FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION` to `beta` in the Application settings. You can do this in the Azure Portal.

This was mentioned https://stackoverflow.com/a/48461404/2896369.